# What percentage of microservice architectures employ polyglot programming models?

Tags: microservices, devsecops

One of the tenets of microservices is the polyglot, [autonomous services](https://nvisium.com/blog/2017/11/16/migrating-to-microservices-securely-safely.html) (developed in different programming languages). In my experience (online reading and YouTube and discussions with developers) it seems this is not really applied in practice except the big companies like NetFlix, AWS , Google. Will this assumption be true ? I  will appreciate information on statistics about this e.g. reports, surveys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good source for statistics could be [stackshare.io](https://stackshare.io/).

In general, polyglot services i.e. *teams* delivering different stacks could create silos, and additional overhead for diverse toolchains; nevertheless I consider that larger organizations have the polyglot situation organically because this type of thing is not always an issue of top-management.

Arguments against polyglot approach:
"[Why You Should Think Twice Before Even Considering Polyglot Microservices](http://codeboje.de/polyglot-microservices/)"

Worth to mention is the polyglot toolkit [Eclipse vert.x](https://vertx.io/) (though I am not sure how is this different to say "it has [bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding) to many languages").

Comment: Very nice article detailing practical issues. As a side note , have you considered using automated code generation tools e.g swagger generator( https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) ? Some of your observations can be handled by such tools e.g polyglot microservices.

Comment: +1 for stackshare.io

Comment: I think for some bolilerplate components code generation indeed makes sense but to have advanced code generated you always need up-to-date generators which are very well synced with language development. Now I look at swagger issues tab and what I see there looks like a high risk.

Comment: I agree, several anwers online support your statement including this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/30342719/3398989. However, there is still potential in this, with maturity and wider usage there is hope in the horizon.